# Mozilla and Chrome do form field autofill at wrong field

Tags: forms, cross-browser, autofill

I am working with React ( but I think it doesn't matter ). Anyway, I have 2 simple forms (login / sign up) and  on the Login Form I have 2 field:
email and password.

on the Sign Up Form I have 3 fields:
email, referral code and password

When I save my password that I entered into the Login form and after that these data will be placed correctly on the same ( LOGIN ) form.

But when I go to the Sign Up form  **autofill data ( email ) is placed in wrong field (in the referral code)**. Password autofill data is placed in the correct password field.

So I tried to add different id's, names etc. It doesn't work. 
Please, if anyone have any information how to resolve this issue tell me I'll be very appropriate for it.

Example of code:
**The Login Form**

```
<form id="signIn" class="auth-form st-form">

   <label class="st-form-label-text valid">

      <input class="st-form-field" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="velidan@rambler.ru" type="text">

   </label>

   <label class="st-form-label-text valid">
      <input class="st-form-field" placeholder="Password" name="password" value="12345678" type="password">
   </label>

  <input class="st-form-submit-btn btn" value="Log in" type="submit">
</form>
```

**The Sign Up Form**

```
<form id="stepOneSignUp" class="auth-form st-form">

   <label for="email" class="st-form-label-text pristine">
      <input id="email" class="st-form-field" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="" type="email">

   </label>

   <label for="referral" class="st-form-label-text referral-code">
      <input id="referral" class="st-form-field" placeholder="Referral Code Placeholder" name="referralCode" value="velidan@rambler.ru" type="text">
   </label>

   <label for="password" class="st-form-label-text pass valid">
      <input id="password" class="st-form-field" placeholder="Password" name="Password" type="password">
   </label>

   <input class="st-form-submit-btn" value="Create new account" type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Steps that need to be taken to make sure the `email`/`username` field on the signup form is correctly saved for the autofill:

- Make sure that your `email`/`username` field is immediately followed by the `password` field, as it seems like the order of the input fields is important.
- Avoid having fields whose names **end** with `name` (e.g. `first_name`, `last_name` - use `first`, `last` instead), as Chrome might wrongly assume and use this field (instead of `email`) for the username autofill.
- if you use only `email` (no `username`) then use `id="username"` for the `email` field (yes, you read that correctly).